# Babel not working with Mocha and starting Node server

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I am running sailsjs, mocha, and babel on sails and mocha. When I run, my before function to start the sails app before running tests, I get this:

```
> PORT=9999 NODE_ENV=test mocha --recursive --compilers js:babel/register



lifting sails
  1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (757ms)
  1 failing

  1)  "before all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: only one instance of babel/polyfill is allowed
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to make mocha running babel and sails running babel at the same time work.

My before() code looks like this:

```
import Sails from 'sails'

// Global before hook
before(function (done) {

  console.log('lifting sails')

  // Lift Sails with test database
  Sails.lift({
    log: {
      level: 'error'
    },
    models: {
      connection: 'testMongoServer',
      migrate: 'drop'
    },
    hooks: {
      // sails-hook-babel: false
      babel: false
    }
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    // Anything else you need to set up
    // ...
    console.log('successfully lifted sails')

    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use sails-hook-babel and it works like a charm. Here to do it:

1. Install `npm install sails-hook-babel --save-dev`
2. Edit your `bootstrap.js`/ before function to load babel, i.e.

   ```
   var Sails   = require('sails'),
       sails;

   var options = {
     loose     : "all",
     stage     : 2,
     ignore    : null,
     only      : null,
     extensions: null
   };

   global.babel   = require("sails-hook-babel/node_modules/babel/register")(options);

   before(function (done) {
     Sails.lift({
       //put your test only config here
     }, function (err, server) {
       sails = server;
       if (err) return done(err);
       // here you can load fixtures, etc.
       done(err, sails);
     });
   });

   after(function (done) {
     // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
     sails.lower(done);
   });
   ```
3. Now you are able to use ES6 within your tests.

Here is the reference:

1. Babel issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/artificialio/sails-hook-babel/issues/1)
2. [My Blog](http://andi.dirgantara.co/blog/menggunakan-es6-pada-sails-js-dengan-babel-js/), sorry it written in Bahasa Indonesia, use Google translate if you want to.